# If for lambda the compiler generated a method instead of a class, how could it leak?

Tags: c#, .net

In the talk "Lowering in C#: What's really going on in your code? - David Wengier" https://youtu.be/gc1AxbNybvw?t=1606 at the 26:39 mark, the presenter says that if the following code:

[image]

was lowered by the compiler to a method:

[image]

this could be a potential problem for memory usage, I quote:

> Because the compiler doesn't know what the body of the lambda does,
>   this could cause the whole class C to have to live on in memory
>   forever. If the class would be Windows.Form, it could have a lot of
>   resources

And then he says, that for this reason, the compiler actually generates a class.

I fail to understand the reasoning how could the memory leak appear.
For example, the C# 7 local functions actually turn into methods, so why wouldn't it work for non-capturing lambdas too?

Comment: You may wish to tweet him your question so he can come and answer it. https://twitter.com/davidwengier?lang=en

Comment: @mjwills I thought about that, but I hope you agree here it's a much larger audience. Also, from a discoverability point of view, a question here might turn out to be useful for many other people too

Comment: @DonBox I think what mjwills meant is that you should keep the question here but also tweet David Wengier a link of the question so that if he's interested, he could come here and leave an answer. That way, you get his point of view in addition to ones from the other answers that the question might receive.

Answer (score 1):

If the compiler generates a non-static method and binds it to an `Action<string>`, the `this` pointer has to be bound along with it whether it is used in the lambda or not. You cannot call a non-static method without a `this` pointer; this is a VM-level restriction that the compiler cannot circumvent. So the `this` pointer is captured and thus keeps the class instance alive as long as the `Action` is alive, which, if it is bound to a long-lived event handler, for example, could be a long time.

But IMO the whole argument starts from the wrong place. He says, "You kind think it conceptually gets lowered to [a method in the same class]." And then he goes on to explain why that's a bad idea. But I think this is a strawman argument. *Why* would the compiler generate a non-static method on the same class in the first place? There is no reason to do that. It is certainly not the line of thinking the C# designers used when coming up with a lowering for lambdas.

The argument should instead go like this: a lambda can capture things it uses (it's a closure). In order to capture them, a place to store them is needed. So the compiler generates a class, which has fields for the captured things.

If the class happens to capture nothing, there are no fields, but there's still a class. Now, the compiler *could*, if the lambda captures nothing, generate a static method in the containing class, or a non-static method if the lambda only catches `this`. But there are two problems with this:

- Those methods could be discovered by reflection.
- It increases the complexity of the compiler (completely separate ways of lowering the lambda for different capture patterns) for no gain (this other way of lowering has no real advantage).

So the compiler simply doesn't do that. The only thing it does, as an optimization, is reuse the same instance of the lambda class every time if the lambda is stateless (i.e. captures nothing). This is just a tiny branch in the existing lowering code and thus has far less complexity.

Comment: Thanks. About the 1st argument, "•Those methods could be discovered by reflection." isn't that the case with other generated stuff too? For example, the compiler actually generates static methods for local functions